# set payment method to paypal in magento with magento soap api

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap, paypal-express

I configured the paypal express on magento site and it works. But  When i want to place an order programmatically and set the payment method to paypal_express in php then it shows the following error.

> Uncaught SoapFault exception: [1008] PayPal gateway has rejected request. Invalid token (#10410: Invalid token)

I will successfully get the payment list and get paypal_express but unable to proceed with payment method.

I m sending the following parameters  in payment method:

```
$paymentMethod = array(
    "method" => paypal_express,<br/>
    "last_trans_id" => "7............",<br/>
"paypal_payer_id" => "W......B.6",<br/>
"paypal_payer_email" => "l........gh@gmail.com",<br/>
"paypal_payer_status" => "verified",<br/>
"paypal_address_status" => "Confirmed",<br/>
"paypal_correlation_id" => "4.....f...d",<br/>
"paypal_express_checkout_payer_id" => "W.....B..6",<br/>
"paypal_express_checkout_token" => ".....................",<br/>
"paypal_payment_status" => "Completed",<br/>
"paypal_protection_eligibility" => "Eligible"

);<br/><br/>
```

So, Help me to place an order with paypal_express

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to place an order of paypal_express with magento soap api.

So , the solution is send manual record to magento by creating custom payment method module.